# Cache behaviour of a function summing up a 2d array

Tags: c, caching, virtual-memory

I'm trying to get the idea of cache and came across this exercise but I don't fully understand it. Consider:

```
int A[2][4]

int sum()
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            sum += A[i][j];
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Assume the following:

- The memory system consists of registers, a single L1 cache and main memory
- The cache is cold when the function is called and the array has been initialized elsewhere
- Variables i,j and sum are all stored in registers
- The array A is aligned in memory such that the first two array elements map to the same cache block.
- sizeof(int) == 4
- The cache is direct mapped with a block size of 8 bytes

a) Suppose that the cache consists of 2 sets. Fill out the table to indicate if the corresponding memory access in A will be a hit (h) or miss (m). Solution:

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|   A   | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| Row 0 |   m   |   m   |   m   |   m   |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| Row 1 |   m   |   m   |   m   |   m   |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

b) What is the pattern of hits and misses if the cache consists of 4 sets instead of 2 sets? Solution:

```
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|   A   | Col 0 | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| Row 0 |   m   |   h   |   m   |   h   |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| Row 1 |   m   |   h   |   m   |   h   |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
```

I'm now trying to get what's going on. I think the first important thing to notice is that c stores arrays using row major but the loop read it in column major. Now my understanding of cache isn't very good yet, but let me try.

So assuming we have a cache of 2 sets and each sets safes 8 bytes. If we access A[i][j] we read an int i.e. 4 bytes. But the cache is 8bytes, to it will read the next integer too. (Which is the reason, switching the loops here would benefit performance, but anyway.)

So here's my thought process:

The array is saved as row-major:

```
A[0][0] A[0][1] A[0][2] A[0][3] A[1][0] A[1][1] A[1][2] A[1][3]

j=0:
    i=0: Read A[0][0] => miss => Set 1: A[0][0] & A[0][1]
    i=1: Read A[1][0] => miss => Set 2: A[1][0] & A[1][1]

j=1:
    i=0: Read A[0][1] => hit since A[0][1] was read into cache at j=0, i=0. Set stays the same.
    i=1: Read A[1][1] => hit since A[1][1] was read into cache at j=0, i=0. Set stays the same.
j=2:
    i=0: Read A[0][2] => miss => Set 1: A[0][2] & A[0][1]
    i=1: Read A[1][2] => miss => Set 2: A[1][2] & A[1][1]
```

We can basically stop here, because I'm already far from the solution and thus this indicates, I don't get how this works.

Where do I fail exactly?

Comment: I am not among the folks around here who can do this problem in their sleep, but I agree with your analysis.  I think the supposed correct solutions you present are in fact wrong, or at least incorrectly matched with the question.  Perhaps they fell out of sync at some time in the past when the question was updated but not the answers.  The answers presented would match the cases where (a) has *one* set and (b) has two.

Comment: Just as a side note: Your explanation does not take [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution) or [cache prefetching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_prefetching) into account. For example, your explanation does not take into account the possibility of a cache miss occuring because a memory address is still being loaded from a previous instruction, but has not finished yet. However, my guess is that the exercise doesn't want you to do that, because the cache behavior would then be unpredictable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger They key to solving it is noticing that it is in fact directly mapped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of your explanation is wrong:

```
    i=1: Read A[1][0] => miss => Set 2: A[1][0] & A[1][1]
```

Since the cache is [direct-mapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Direct-mapped_cache), it will be stored in set 1, not set 2, overwriting the previous cache entry.

Your explanation would be correct for a fully associative cache, but the exercise states that the cache is direct-mapped, which means it is one-way set associative.

What actually happens is the following:

First, I will mark cache line boundaries with "|" and specify which cache set they map to:

```
A[0][0] A[0][1] | A[0][2] A[0][3] | A[1][0] A[1][1] | A[1][2] A[1][3]
     Set 1      |      Set 2      |      Set 1      |      Set 2
```

Now, here is what happens:

```
j=0:
    i=0: Read A[0][0]
        => miss (Set 1 is cold)
        => Set 1: A[0][0] & A[0][1]
    i=1: Read A[1][0]
        => miss (since A[1][0] was never loaded into Set 1 yet)
        => Set 1: A[1][0] & A[1][1]

j=1:
    i=0: Read A[0][1]
        => miss (since A[0][1] was evicted from Set 1)
        => Set 1: A[0][0] & A[0][1]
    i=1: Read A[1][1]
        => miss (since A[1][1] was evicted from Set 1)
        => Set 1: A[1][0] & A[1][1]

j=2:
    i=0: Read A[0][2]
        => miss (Set 2 is cold)
        => Set 2: A[0][2] & A[0][3]
    i=1: Read A[1][2]
        => miss (since A[1][2] was never loaded into Set 2 yet)
        => Set 2: A[1][2] & A[1][3]

j=3:
    i=0: Read A[0][3]
        => miss (since A[0][3] was evicted from Set 2)
        => Set 2: A[0][2] & A[0][3]
    i=1: Read A[1][3]
        => miss (since A[1][3] was evicted from Set 2)
        => Set 2: A[1][2] & A[1][3]
```

The main problem is that the cache line you need always gets evicted from cache before you have a chance to access it again. This is due to the poor access pattern used to access the array ([column major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) instead of row major). Only one set of the cache is used at once, instead of the entire cache (both sets). This is ineffcient and causes unnecessary cache evictions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I'm still unsure which set is used when. When is set 2 being used in the given example?

Comment: The 1st and 3rd cache line (called "cache block" in your question) can only be stored in set 1 whereas the 2nd and 4th cache line can only be stored in set 2. In your explanation, you were storing the 3rd cache line in set 2.

Comment: The difference between a fully associative cache and a direct-mapped cache is explained in the Wikipedia article that I linked to.

Comment: To associate a memory address with a set, the formula is: "(address / cache_line_size) [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) num_sets"

Comment: Just for clarification: When I say "cache line", I do not mean memory that is cached. I rather mean a block of memory of 8 bytes (two int elements) that fits into a single cache entry. I am dividing the array A into 4 cache lines, because the cache line size is 8 bytes.

Comment: The 2nd cache line consists of A[0][2] and A[0][3] whereas the 4th cache line consists of A[1][2] and A[1][3]. Only these elements can be cached by set 2, all other elements must be cached by set 1.

Comment: Of course I read you article. I see. The thing here is that although I actually do have the next wanted value in my cache, I can't access it, since it's directly mapped. The first iteration of the inner loop maps to the first set, and the second iteration of the inner loop maps to the second set. The value I want in the second is set 1, so that doesn't benefit me, since I can't access it since it's directly mapped. (and vice-versa). I hope I got that correct now :) Thanks

Comment: I have now updated my answer with a detailed explanation of what happens.

Comment: Your statement that the first iteration of the inner loop maps to the first set and the second iteration to the second set, is incorrect. The problem is that they both map to the same set (so only half the cache is actively used and the other half is wasted).

Comment: @xotix: The problem is not that you have the wanted value in cache and can't access it, but rather that whenever there is a value in cache that you will need later, it will get evicted before you access it again.

Comment: Okay considering what you said, that makes sense. I can't figure out how you know which sets are being used and which aren't. I reread the article but I guess I'm just lacking terminology to properly deduce the knowledge out of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206053/discussion-between-andreas-wenzel-and-xotix).

Comment: @xotix: Were you able to read my chat messages? I don't know whether you have given up on trying to understand or whether you are having connection issues.